# Pandas the most efficient way of assigning a sequence of values to particular positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty pandas dataframe (`df`), a list of (index, column) pairs (`pair_list`), and a list of corresponding values (`value_list`). I want to assign the value in `value_list` to the corresponding position in `df` according to `pair_list`. The following code is what I am using currently, but it is slow. Is there any faster way to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3], columns=['a', 'b','c','d'])
pair_list = [(0,'a'),(1,'c'),(0,'d')]
value_list = np.array([3,2,4])
for pos, item in enumerate(pair_list):
    df.at[item] = value_list[pos]
```

The output of the code should be:

```
     a    b    c    d
0    3  NaN  NaN    4
1  NaN  NaN    2  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is create a `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html), then create a `Series`, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and add missing columns, index values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
pair_list = [(0,'a'),(1,'c'),(0,'d')]
value_list = np.array([3,2,4])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pair_list)

cols = ['a', 'b','c','d']
idx = [0,1,2,3]
df = pd.Series(value_list, index=mux).unstack().reindex(index=idx, columns=cols)
print (df)
     a   b    c    d
0  3.0 NaN  NaN  4.0
1  NaN NaN  2.0  NaN
2  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
```